# Regex don't find matches in Ruby 1.8.7 but does in 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-1.8.7

I'm trying to validate UK zip codes in Ruby.  I stumbled upon this regex on stackoverflow:

```
(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})
```

It works great in Ruby 1.9.2 and 2.0.0 (see http://rubular.com/r/GKgLdIFvNJ) but I'm working with 1.8.7.  What can I do?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: It **`did work`** or **`didn't work`** when you tested it in `Ruby 1.8.7`?

Comment: it wasn't working for 1.8.7, i tried stema's solution on rubar it's working now there. Let me test in my script and i'll update you!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you find this expression? I assume it was not written for Ruby.

Ruby is not supporting character class subtraction. So 1.9.2 is accepting [A-Z-[QVX]] but is **not working as expected**. Those characters are **not** excluded from the char class ([See rubular](http://rubular.com/r/AEXzfgl3dM), QVX is still matched)

1.8.7 is **not** accepting this expression at all.

You have to rewrite all those character ranges like this:

`[A-Z-[QVX]]` becomes `[A-PR-UWYZ]`

[See on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UQnkqpXqpq)

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm!!
PS: I hate working on 1.8.7 just bcoz these silly reasons!!

Comment: You are welcome, but I think the behaviour of 1.8.7 is better here IMO. From 1.9.2 they accept the pattern, **but it is not interpreted as you expect**.